# Двоих, троих, десятерых

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, выбор-слов, числительные

Можно ли сказать поделить на "двадцать человек" одним словом, по аналогии с двоих, троих, десятерых?

Answer (score 2):

> В состав [собирательных числительных](https://www.aatseel.org/100111/pdf/6a5_2_mikaelian.pdf) по разным оценкам входят от девяти до двадцати лексем, однако статус их различен. Наиболее полный список включает числительные *оба, двое, трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро, восьмеро, девятеро, десятеро* и еще десять «потенциальных», редко употребительных лексем (*одиннадцатеро – **двадцатеро***).

И. Микаэлян, Анна А. Зализняк

При склонении мы получаем форму *[десятерых](https://books.google.ee/books?id=rxgoDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85&source=bl&ots=ntLnLVvIZi&sig=ACfU3U3Dq7lc-f0DNcXjVfRiPTMP48D5ow&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT5e3sqOPgAhUBqIsKHX_TB48Q6AEwCHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85&f=false), двадцатерых* (нечасто, но все-таки встречается).

*Не для хвастовства, а для ясности скажу: тех обязанностей, которые лежали на мне, хватило бы разделить **на десятерых*** (И. Оболенский. Пастернак, Нагибин, их друг Рихтер и другие).

*— Тебе не кажется, что делить выкуп за дочку градоправителя **на двадцатерых** не слишком выгодно?* (А. Кочуров. И кто тут попал?)